# Can't freeze DOMStringList. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I run the following statement in Chrome:

```
Object.freeze(location.ancestorOrigins)
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot freeze

`location.ancestorOrigins` returns an object of type `DOMStringList`. So why can't we freeze objects of this type?